# How to use multiple order by with different colums of different tables on one table Mysql?

Tags: mysql

1) TABLE 1)

This is one table operators, having three columns id is the primary_key.

```
mysql> select id, name, status from operators limit 10;
    +----+-----------------------+---------------+
    | id | name                  | status        |
    +----+-----------------------+---------------+
    |  1 | abcde Travels         | Active        |
    |  2 | bcdef Tourists        | Active        |
    |  3 | cdefg Travels         | Active        |
    |  4 | defgh Travels         | Active        |
    |  5 | efghi Travels         | Active        |
    |  6 | fghij Travels         | Active        |
    |  7 | ghijk Travels         | Paid Operator |
    |  8 | hijkl Travels         | Active        |
    |  9 | ijklm Travels         | Active        |
    | 10 | jklmn Travels         | Paid Operator |
    +----+-----------------------+---------------+
```

2) TABLE 2

This is operator_api_config table where we are having operator_id as a foreign_key and lcc one column.

```
mysql> select id, operator_id,lcc from operator_api_configs limit 10;

+----+-------------+------+
| id | operator_id | lcc  |
+----+-------------+------+
|  1 |           1 | 0.00 |
|  2 |           2 | 2.00 |
|  3 |           3 | 0.00 |
|  4 |           4 | 0.00 |
|  5 |           5 | 0.00 |
|  6 |           6 | 0.00 |
|  7 |           7 | 0.00 |
|  8 |           8 | 0.00 |
|  9 |           9 | 0.00 |
| 10 |          10 | 3.00 |
+----+-------------+------+
```

3) TABLE 3

This is Main table schedules where multiple columns are there and operator_id is a foreign_key.

```
mysql> select id, origin_id,destination_id,departure_time,available_seats, operator_id,ADDTIME(TIMESTAMP(travel_date,(STR_TO_DATE(departure_time,'%h:%i%p'))), duration) as arrival_date_time from schedules limit 10;

+--------+-----------+----------------+----------------+-----------------+-------------+---------------------+
| id     | origin_id | destination_id | departure_time | available_seats | operator_id | arrival_date_time   |
+--------+-----------+----------------+----------------+-----------------+-------------+---------------------+
| 797263 |       134 |            251 | 10:45 PM       |              0  |          5  | 2014-08-26 06:00:00 |
| 794764 |       134 |            251 | 10:15 PM       |              19 |          4  | 2014-08-26 05:00:00 |
| 794892 |       134 |            251 | 11:30 PM       |              51 |          5  | 2014-08-26 06:00:00 |
| 794936 |       134 |            251 | 03:00 PM       |              51 |          10  | 2014-08-25 22:00:00 |
| 776582 |       134 |            251 | 07:30 AM       |              0  |           7  | 2014-08-25 16:30:00 |
| 776612 |       134 |            251 | 10:30 PM       |              25 |           7  | 2014-08-26 06:00:00 |
| 776591 |       134 |            251 | 10:15 AM       |              25 |           7  | 2014-08-25 17:45:00 |
| 776622 |       134 |            251 | 11:15 PM       |              29 |           8  | 2014-08-26 07:15:00 |
| 776601 |       134 |            251 | 03:30 PM       |               0 |           10 | 2014-08-25 23:15:00 |
| 776661 |       134 |            251 | 09:45 PM       |              33 |           10 | 2014-08-26 05:45:00 |
+--------+-----------+----------------+----------------+-----------------+-------------+---------------------+
```

Expected output :

1) Paid operators(status in operators table) Schedules should come first in the list(List i need to show on UI) which is having available_seats > 0 in schedules table.

2) In Paid operators Schedules should come first which operator is having more lcc(in operator_api_config table).

3) Full list should be in ascending order by departure_time.

4) All the available_seats < 0 in schedules table should come down(all Paid operators and active operators too).

```
+--------+-----------+----------------+----------------+-----------------+-------------+---------------------+
| id     | origin_id | destination_id | departure_time | available_seats | operator_id | arrival_date_time   |
+--------+-----------+----------------+----------------+-----------------+-------------+---------------------+
| 794936 |       134 |            251 | 03:00 PM       |              51 |          10 | 2014-08-25 22:00:00 |
| 776661 |       134 |            251 | 09:45 PM       |              33 |          10 | 2014-08-26 05:45:00 |
| 776591 |       134 |            251 | 10:15 AM       |              25 |           7 | 2014-08-25 17:45:00 |
| 776612 |       134 |            251 | 10:30 PM       |              25 |           7 | 2014-08-26 06:00:00 |
| 794764 |       134 |            251 | 10:15 PM       |              19 |           4 | 2014-08-26 05:00:00 |
| 776622 |       134 |            251 | 11:15 PM       |              29 |           8 | 2014-08-26 07:15:00 |
| 794892 |       134 |            251 | 11:30 PM       |              51 |           5 | 2014-08-26 06:00:00 |
| 776582 |       134 |            251 | 07:30 AM       |              0  |           7 | 2014-08-25 16:30:00 |
| 776601 |       134 |            251 | 03:30 PM       |              0  |           10| 2014-08-25 23:15:00 |
| 797263 |       134 |            251 | 10:45 PM       |              0  |           5 | 2014-08-26 06:00:00 |
+--------+-----------+----------------+----------------+-----------------+-------------+---------------------+
```

I tried with this Query:

```
select sch.id, sch.origin_id,sch.destination_id, sch.departure_time,sch.available_seats, sch.operator_id, ADDTIME(TIMESTAMP(travel_date,(STR_TO_DATE(departure_time,'%h:%i%p'))), duration) as arrival_date_time from schedules as sch  
INNER JOIN operators as ope on sch.operator_id = ope.id 
INNER JOIN operator_api_configs as opconf on ope.id = opconf.operator_id 
WHERE ((ADDTIME(TIMESTAMP(sch.travel_date,(STR_TO_DATE(sch.departure_time,'%h:%i%p'))), sch.duration) >= NOW())) and sch.origin_id = '134' and sch.destination_id = '251' 
ORDER BY ope.status desc, opconf.lcc desc, (sch.available_seats <= 0 && (STR_TO_DATE(sch.departure_time,'%h:%i%p') >= TIME(NOW()))), STR_TO_DATE(sch.departure_time,'%h:%i%p');
```

OUTPUT:

```
+--------+-----------+----------------+----------------+-----------------+-------------+---------------------+
| id     | origin_id | destination_id | departure_time | available_seats | operator_id | arrival_date_time   |
+--------+-----------+----------------+----------------+-----------------+-------------+---------------------+
| 794936 |       134 |            251 | 03:00 PM       |              51 |          10 | 2014-08-25 22:00:00 |
| 776601 |       134 |            251 | 03:30 PM       |              0  |          10 | 2014-08-25 23:15:00 |
| 776661 |       134 |            251 | 09:45 PM       |              33 |          10 | 2014-08-26 05:45:00 |
| 776582 |       134 |            251 | 07:30 AM       |              0  |           7 | 2014-08-25 16:30:00 |
| 776591 |       134 |            251 | 10:15 AM       |              25 |           7 | 2014-08-25 17:45:00 |
| 776612 |       134 |            251 | 10:30 PM       |              25 |           7 | 2014-08-26 06:00:00 |
| 794764 |       134 |            251 | 10:15 PM       |              19 |           4 | 2014-08-26 05:00:00 |
| 776622 |       134 |            251 | 11:15 PM       |              29 |           8 | 2014-08-26 07:15:00 |
| 794892 |       134 |            251 | 11:30 PM       |              51 |           5 | 2014-08-26 06:00:00 |
| 797263 |       134 |            251 | 10:45 PM       |              0  |           5 | 2014-08-26 06:00:00 |
+--------+-----------+----------------+----------------+-----------------+-------------+---------------------+
```

Here i want that all available_seats < 0 should come down with order by departure_time coulmn...

Comment: Please check updated question i added what i tried .. @T.J.Crowder

Comment: Okay, and what was wrong with the result?

Comment: available_seats < 0 should come down but it is coming up only... I mean available_seats < 0 (for both Paid operator as well as Active operator) should come down, here what is happening : order by operators.status desc so all schedules are coming with order.

Comment: I added output(table) also please check it.. @T.J.Crowder

Comment: Your primary sort criterion is on `ope.status`, so of course that's going to happen first. The first sort happens first, then the next happens *within* the first, and so on.

Comment: So How can i get Expected output is there any way ... can you tell the sorting order by  @T.J.Crowder

Comment: Sorry, I don't have time right now to study your data set and come up with how to sort it for you. But just think in terms of what the main order is you want, then put that first; then within that order, what's the next order you want? Put that second. Etc. Good luck with it.

Comment: Yeah, I will, Thanks for wishes... :) @T.J.Crowder

Comment: I did it :)  @T.J.Crowder